# Catching User Input in discord.js for a Rock, Paper, Scissors Application

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a discord.js bot that has a Rock, Paper, Scissors command. The code below is my last attempt at catching a user response.

The response after the command does not have a prefix and I have been trying to get it to work without one.

```js
var rps = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var rpsChoice = rps[Math.floor(Math.random() * rps.length)];

message.channel.send("Let us play Rock, Paper, Scissors. Please type in the corresponding responses.").then(() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === "rock" || response.content === "paper" || response.content === "scissors", {
        max: 1,
        time: 45000,
        errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
        if (user == "rock" && rpsChoice == "scissors") {
            message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${collected}`);
            message.channel.send("You win! Congrats!");
        } else if (collected == "paper" && rpsChoice == "rock") {
            message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${collected}`);
            message.channel.send("You win! Congrats!");
        } else if (collected == "scissors" && rpsChoice == "paper") {
            message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${collected}`);
            message.channel.send("You win! Congrats");
        } else if (collected == rpsChoice) {
            message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${collected}`);
            message.channel.send("No one wins, we tied!");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("I'm sorry, you lost!");
        }

    }).catch(() => {
        message.channel.send("You didn't respond with anything!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Some clarity please? What is your problem? Based on this line: `The response after the command does not have a prefix and I have been trying to get it to work without one.` You've been trying to get it to work **without** a prefix? Yet you say the command *does not have* one.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer Sorry, the command in order to run the command has a prefix but typing in "rock", "paper", and "scissors" does not. Does that clarify it?

Comment: Well I figured that, but do you want the *response* to have a prefix or not? Cuz atm it looks like the code accepts answers without prefixes.

Comment: @Frustratedprogrammer No, I want the prefix to not have a prefix.

Comment: Um then just remove the prefix I guess? I still don't understand... do you want the user to send smt like `>rps` then `>rock`? Your code appears to accept `>rps` then `rock`

Comment: I want it it like the second thing you did

Comment: So then whats the problem? What is it *currently* doing? Your code looks correct based on what you described... I am not sure what you're doing to run the `rps` command. If you don't know how to run it try this `if( message.content.toLowerCase() === ">rps"){ your code thats you got right now }`

Comment: So, my command is ".rps"

When I type "rock", "paper", "scissors", the bot automatically sends the "You didn't send anything" message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212216/discussion-between-frustrated-programmer-and-jiangxi123).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you have a few issues:

here: `if (user == "rock" && rpsChoice == "scissors") {` it looks like `user` isn't defined.

Secondly `collected` is a *collection* of messages. NOT the message's content. So doing `collected == "paper"` is similar to comparing an **Object** to a **String**.

Third using two equals `==` can generally cause issues when comparing things and is highly recommended against using it. It's fine to use, but only when you know what your doing.

So to fix all three issues use this *inside the `.then()` function*:

```js
let response = collection.first().content.toLowerCase();
if (response === "rock" && rpsChoice == "scissors") {
    message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${collected}`);
    message.channel.send("You win! Congrats!");
} else if (response === "paper" && rpsChoice == "rock") {
    message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${response}`);
    message.channel.send("You win! Congrats!");
} else if (response === "scissors" && rpsChoice == "paper") {
    message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${response}`);
    message.channel.send("You win! Congrats");
} else if (response  === rpsChoice) {
    message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${response}`);
    message.channel.send("No one wins, we tied!");
} else {
    //Hey did ya realize you don't tell the user what the bot's choice was when they lost?
    message.channel.send("I'm sorry, you lost!");
}
```

And just a tip, to reduce code, remove all the

```js
message.channel.send(`I chose ${rpsChoice} and you chose ${response}`);
```

and put it **right after** the definition of `response`